# C++ AVRO , CMAKE failed

Tags: cmake

I am building `AVRO C++`, but when I build with CMAKE, I have some troubles. My CMAKE version is `3.5`, and Boost version is `1.73.0`.

Error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.73.0/BoostConfig.cmake:240 (if):
  if given arguments:
    "ALL" "IN_LIST" "Boost_FIND_COMPONENTS"
  Unknown arguments specified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is specified in [CMP0057](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/policy/CMP0057.html). You should either bump the minimum CMake version of your project to 3.3:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
```

or explicitly set the policy to the NEW behavior:

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0057 NEW)
```